SMEG SNL90D constantly resetting
I have an issue with a SMEG SNL90D shown below:

It is an oven and cooker combo, and the digital clock is constantly resetting. This disables the oven functionality but leaves the ignition spark for the gas working. From this, I deduce something is tripping in the clock part specifically, and the oven depends on that.
After the computer resets, it goes into reset mode (blinking), and I need to press the 2nd and 3rd buttons. When I do this, the oven often resets itself again, the screen turns off, or it's displaying garbage. The behavior is inconsistent, making it hard to recreate the problem and troubleshoot. The resetting seems to occur at random moments and intervals, unrelated to the usage of the oven.
I've uploaded videos of three cases of resetting the clock:

Video 1
Video 2
Video 3

I found this video, which deals with the repair of a similar clock, but it has different problems, so I'm not sure if it would be the solution to my problem.
Device information:

SMEG SNL90D
Purchase date unknown (left to us by previous owners)
Label on the back of the oven:



Picture of the clock/computer unit:


Could anybody advise on how to troubleshoot? I'm fine with opening up the oven and doing repairs, but I have not done any work with ovens before, so any guidance is highly appreciated.

Digital clock resetting at random implies inconsistent power supply.
Oven depending on the clock probably just means the oven depends on the clock (which gets upset by power interruptions) so if the clock isn't happy, the oven isn't happy. Does not appear to imply there's specifically a problem with the oven, internally.
I'd go looking for a bad/loose connection somewhere between the circuit breaker supplying the circuit and the input to the oven and cooker combo. Only after eliminating that would I even consider the interior wiring of the oven and cooker.

I think you're correct in saying that there's no issue with the oven. It happily works as long as the clock does not reset.

In the repair video I linked to, the person indicates that the capacitors are faulty. Could that be the cause of the inconsistent power supply?

Possibly, but not, as already stated, the place I'd start looking.
